# Transfer of credit (masters) in Germany?

Tags: masters, germany, transfer-student

Is it possible to transfer credit (masters) in Germany? I have completed half of my credits in a German university. Now I want to transfer to other university. Is it possible?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I wrote to some program coordinators of different universities(of course the same subject)  and they said I have to take admission from the beginning. Thats why I was not sure whether its possible in Germany or not.

Comment: Formally, they have to accept the credits you have already earned, But some universities haven't gotten the word yet, unfortunately.

Answer (score 8):

Credits *must¹* be transferred if you are changing universities, this includes courses you have failed. Any course with the appropriate amount of credits that is 80 % or more equivalent to a course in the program you are transferring to will be transferred. Be prepared to do the paperwork, documenting the “Modulhandbuch” for all of the courses you have attempted.

You can only transfer, however, if there is space available in the target program. This is not always the case.

---

¹ This is demanded by federal law ([Hochschulrahmengesetz, § 15(3)](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/hrg/__15.html)):

> Zum Nachweis von Studien- und Prüfungsleistungen soll ein Leistungspunktsystem geschaffen werden, das auch die Übertragung erbrachter Leistungen auf andere Studiengänge […] einer anderen Hochschule ermöglicht.
>
> (For certifying studying or examination accomplishments, a point-based system system shall be created that allows to transfer accomplishments to other degree courses of other universities.)

Specific realisations depend on the state or even the university. For example, the [Berliner Hochschulgesetz](http://www.tu-berlin.de/fileadmin/i48/BT/Infomaterial/Allgemeine_Infos/Gesetze__Richtlinien__Verordnungen/BerlHG_-_Berliner_Hochschulgesetz.pdf) states (§ 22 (2)):

> Die Hochschulen haben Studiengänge und Prüfungen so zu organisieren
>   und einzurichten, dass insbesondere
>
> […]
>
> 6. bereits erbrachte Studien- und Prüfungsleistungen bei einem Wechsel der
>      Hochschule weitestgehend anerkannt werden können,
>
> […]
>
> (Universities have to organise courses and exams such that especially […] already achieved studying or examination accomplishments can be largely acknowledged when switching universities.)

Comment: I have looked in some universities.Most of the universities in Germany does not take students in higher semesters.May be I should search in other countries of Europe.

Comment: I don't think that "most" is true. See the legal language that Wrzlprmft kindly put into my answer. It depends on whether or not there is space available in the program. Transferring credit to other European countries is theoretically possible, but in general an exercise in frustration. Note that there are deadlines for application to Master's programs, some as early as April or May, to commence studies in the fall.

Comment: Yes u r right.I wrote to some coordinators now and some of them said its possible.they asked me to provide them my module to see how much my courses match to them. Now my question when i will write them,sholud i ask the main supervisor(the head person who is responsible for the programme) also to consider or just the coordinator?is it ok if i write the head a mail also? does it make any difference?as u r in the same profession so i think u know what professors like u think. @Debora Weber-Wulff

Comment: Write to the coordinator. It is their job, they answered you. As department head I detested getting CCed on every trivial matter. Even though this is important for you, it is NOT of interest to the department head. Only deal with the person in charge of such a thing. In Germany this would be the ''Prüfungsausschussvorsitzende''.